# Macro to create multiple similar identifiers for testing

Tags: c++, macros, identifier

I wanted to write a simple macro to expand some identifiers so it saves me the work of typing everything again and again when I have similar code to test for many different classes.

I wanted something like this:

```
#define TST(x)  x## x##_1(2);                   \
                x## x##_2;                      \
                                                \
                x##_1.print(cout);              \
                x##_2.print(cout);              \
                x##_2.elem(3);                  \
                x##_2.elem(4);                  \
                x##_2.print(cout)
```

To be translated into

```
Pentagonal Pentagonal_1(2);
Pentagonal Pentagonal_2;

Pentagonal_1.print(cout);
Pentagonal_2.print(cout);
Pentagonal_2.elem(3);
Pentagonal_2.elem(4);
Pentagonal_2.print(cout);
```

whenever I call

```
TST(Pentagonal);
```

so far it is being translated glued together like

```
PentagonalPentagonal_1
```

I tried searching for this but in this specific case I couldn't find much help elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
#define TST(x)  x## x##_1(2);                   \
                x## x##_2;                      \

...
```

to

```
#define TST(x)  x x##_1(2);                   \
                x x##_2;                      \

...
```

`##` is the token-paste operator: It "absorbs" surrounding whitespace and joins neighboring tokens into one.

The extras you had up there were pasting the `Pentagonal` and `Pentagonal_1` together.

Comment: i was sure I did that, but it seems now it works. I'd upvote you but I'm still not eligible, will work more helping people here as soon as I'm done with college. Thanks